# How to configure a sigma function so that it only counts every third number

Tags: summation, notation

I have a sigma function where the start value is *k* and the operation can **only** be counted when *k* is a multiple of 3. I know how to differentiate between even and odd numbers in a sigma function, but how do I differentiate between numbers that are multiples of 3, and numbers that are not?

Comment: $\sum 3i ${}{}{}{}}{}}

Comment: You don't distinguish, you just count normally and multiply the index by $3$. For example, $\sum\limits_if(3i)$.

Comment: @DonThousand The problem with that is that the 3i cannot exceed the n-value, which it will if I simply write 3i. If n is 10, then the last i will be 10, where only the 3, 6 and 9 actually added anything to the sum.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question needs more clarity. I am not completely sure if this is what you meant to ask, but to denote the sum of the values of a function at all natural numbers divisible by 3 greater than or equal to $k$, you can use $\sum_{n=\left \lceil {k \over 3} \right\rceil}^{\infty}f(3n)$. Alternatively, you can use an index set $S=\{ n \in \mathbb{N} | (\exists m \in  \mathbb{N} ,n=3\cdot m) \wedge (k \leq n)\}$ and denote the sum as $\sum_{i \in S}f(i)$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Y. Tamer of modifying the index set is probably the most reasonable for most applications. However, if you don't want to modify the index set, you can use an indicator function:

Define $g:\mathbb Z\to\{0,1\}$ so that $g(n)=1$ if $n$ is a multiple of $3$ and $g(n)=0$ if $n$ is not a multiple of $3$. Then you can write
$$\sum_{\substack{i\in S\\3|i}}f(i)=\sum_{i\in S}f(i)g(i).$$